# UIView between rows in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to implement the rating system described in [this article](https://medium.com/circa/the-right-way-to-ask-users-to-review-your-app-9a32fd604fca#.a0110osnk).

In the UICollectionView the rows contain two cells as you can see in the image below. Now, sometimes I want an extra row with one UIView below the first row. How would I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Why not just make it a cell as well? And return a different size for that cell in your UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: I don't understand how I didn't come up with that in the first place. Any idea how I can improve the `indexPath.row-1` after the green block?

Comment: If you use UICollectionViewFlowLayout you can not insert UIView between cells. You have to implement your own layout for such cases.